# C# How to access http referer (and URL) information in webbrowser control

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I am using web browser control in a winforms application(vs2008, C#).

Is there any way to view http request & response headers on web browser control while navigation to different pages.

How to get "Referer" information of the web request during web browser control's page navigation? And how to get the url executed in the background? (For example HTTP Code 200 & 204 the ones you don't see navigated on the webbrowser but are executed, you can see if them with a tool like fiddler)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1, seems like a fairly thought out question and I wouldnt mind knowing myself. No idea why someone marked it down.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do it from the WebBrowser control itself, it doesn't expose any request/response objects.  Maybe going interop you can intercept some windows message or something!?  Is Fiddler written in .NET?

Comment: Have you looked into the [`Navigated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigated.aspx) or [`Navigating`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigating.aspx) events on the `WebBrowser` control?  They might have access to that information.

Comment: @Gromer I have taken a look I think Navigated or Navigating will not works for this instance because those navigation happen in the background I do not know how to call it, So far can't find a solution and the more I search in google the more confused I'm! :(! Help me guys!

Comment: do you want to 'see' it or 'change' it? you can use fiddler to sniff the traffic and see it. you can also use firebug in firefox to see it too.

Comment: @urlreader I know how to see it, I need to see in the webbrowser control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this links for getting web browser request and response:

[Http-Monitor-for-Webbrowser-Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/157329/Http-Monitor-for-Webbrowser-Control)

[capturing-all-requests-and-responses-from-the-web-browser-control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494811/capturing-all-requests-and-responses-from-the-web-browser-control)

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use [FiddlerCore](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler/fiddlercore), which I've found quite handy.